# Retrieve the -data field of Tk virtual events in python event handeler

Tags: python, events, tkinter

Tcl/Tk allows for the generation of virtual events via the following syntax:

```
event generate .myWidget <<whatever>> -data "arbitrary text here"
```

A Tcl/Tk handle bound to this event would allow one to access the value of the `-data` option via the `%d` substitution.  From python, I can bind to this event:

```
def on_whatever(event):
    print("Meh")

myWidget.bind("<<whatever>>", on_whatever, add="+")
```

This works fine for me up to this point, but I can not find any way from python to access the tcl/tk event's `-data` field.

Comment: Looks like shortcoming of tkinter. In Python 3.2 tkinter.Misc._substitute, which creates event objects, there's a line saying "# Missing: (a, c, d, m, o, v, B, R)". I think d refers to -data here.

Comment: I'm in similar trouble and I decided to use the virtual event just for notification and a shared queue for storing event data.

Answer (score 0):

You might have to use a separate variable/attribute.

When it's time to call event_generate(), you can set the variable to whatever you like.

```
from Tkinter import *
root = Tk()
attr = None

def blahblah(event):
    print attr

root.bind('<<shazzam>>', blahblah, '+')

def do_something():
    global attr
    attr = 'arbitrary text here'
    root.event_generate('<<shazzam>>')

root.after(3000, do_something)
root.mainloop()
```

Comment: This is much easier than the linked duplicate answer. Though I'd keep the state in a class rather than a global.